# Robocopy not copying 66% of files

Tags: robocopy

I need to move the contents of a network share to another location and am trying to use robocopy to do this - robocopy /mir   /tee /log:logfile.txt

This runs and returns no errors - but when I compare the 2 folders there is a huge difference in the number/size of files:

- Source folder has 1,615,830 files in 49,831 directories totalling
  365gb/369gb on disk
- Destination folder has 511,728 files in 16,007    directories
  totalling 171gb/176gb on disc

Is there an obvious reason for this? I switched to /mir from /e but it made no difference at all. There are no hidden or system files in the source although I believe that robocopy would copy them anyway. Both source and destination have plenty of free space.

Server is Windows 2019 standard, source is on a NetApp SAN, destination is on a Huawei SAN

Comment: Is it possible that files with the same title are going into the same folder?  I think robocopy kills the second instance of an identical title, but it's been a while since I worked with robocopy.